# NIFI site to site communication

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 2 machines:

1st machine installed with `nifi` and Site to Site properties:

```
# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=
nifi.remote.input.secure=false
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=8055
```

2nd machine is running spark code, connected to nifi as below.

I am able to access the web nifi here in second instance.

```
 val conf = new SiteToSiteClient.Builder()
       .url("http://x.x.x.x:xxx/nifi")
       .portName("DatatoSpark")
       .buildConfig()
```

However, data is not coming through the spark code through outport.

If I run the nifi on the same machine then data is getting pulled from spark code.

Comment: Please format code as code and normal text as normal text.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any stacktraces from the logs you can share? Your `nifi.remote.input.host` value is empty in `nifi.properties`. Have you tried populating it with the hostname you wish to use? Also ensure that in your Spark code you are referencing the `nifi.web.http.port` value, rather than the `nifi.remote.input.socket.port` value (in this case, likely 8080 vs. 8055) to initiate the Site to Site communication. S2S discovers other NiFi instances over the main web port.